# Copied Python environment using other version than the specified one

Tags: python, cmd

I'm trying to launch a python scripts from a copied embeded venv into an app. (A webpage that calls python script as back).
But when it lauches the scripts, the console triggers error
`No python at c:\users\...\Appdata\local\program\python38\python.exe`

The problem is that the command i enter specifies that i wanna use my embedded python version
`path/to/my/python/back/python.exe myscript`

I imagin it's because i've not really installed python and just copied it, but is there a way to resolve the issue?

the whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>YoutubeDL</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/index.css?v=2">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="FA/css/all.min.css">
    <script src="FA/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="loading" class="loading">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="titles">
            <div id="title">Youtube Downloader</div>
            <div id="subtitle">Enter Url</div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Url..." class="form-control" id="url">
        <div id="debug"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blackScreen" class="loading"></div>
    <div id="modal">
        <div id="cross"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
        <div id="modalContent">
            toto
        </div>
        <div id="bonhomme">
            :/
        </div>
        <div id="log">
            <a id="gotolog">Cliquez ici pour plus de détails</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const $ = jQuery = require("jquery");
    const {exec} = require("child_process");
    const fs = require("fs");

    const logFile = __dirname;

    const modal = $("#modal");
    const modanCtnt = $("#modalContent");
    const loading = $("#loading");
    const blackScreen = $("#blackScreen");
    const mainjq = $("#main");
    const log = $("#log");

    window.onload = ()=>{
        let margin = (window.innerWidth - document.getElementById("main").style.width)/3.4;
        mainjq.css("margin-left", margin + "px");
    }

    window.onresize = ()=>{
        let margin = (window.innerWidth - document.getElementById("main").style.width)/3.4;
        mainjq.css("margin-left", margin + "px");
    }

    document.getElementById("url").onkeypress = (e)=>{
        if(e.key==="Enter"){
            if(document.getElementById("url").value.includes("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")){
                load();
                download(document.getElementById("url").value);
            } else {
                fillModal("Erreur : URL incorrect");
            }
        }
    }

    async function download(url){
/* HERE THE COMMANDE THAT I USE TO CALL MY EMBEDDED PY SCRIPT*/
        let command = "cd " + '"'+__dirname + "\\py"+ '"'+" && "
            +__dirname + "\\py\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe "+
            __dirname + "\\py\\main.py "+ url + " " + process.env.USERPROFILE + "\\Downloads\\";
       exec(command, (err)=>{
           if(err){
alert(err)
               fillModal("Une erreur interne est survenue...", false);
               return 0;
           } else {
               document.getElementById("url").value = "";
               $("#debug").html("Vidéo téléchargée avec succès <i class=\"fas fa-thumbs-up\"></i>");

           }
           noLoad();
       });
    }

    function load(){
        loading.show();
    }

    function noLoad(){
        loading.hide();
    }

    function fillModal(html, log=false){
        blackScreen.show();
        modal.show();
        modanCtnt.html(html);
        if(log){
            log.show();
        } else {
            log.hide();
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("cross").onclick = ()=>{
        modal.hide()
        blackScreen.hide();
    }

    document.getElementById("gotolog").onclick = ()=>{
        exec("start "+'"'+__dirname+"\\ytdl.log" + '"');
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Add Python to your path in environmental variables.

Comment: Is there a way to do it programatically?

Comment: **Do not** add the location of your `python.exe` directory to your `Path` environment variable value data. Instead, what you need to do, before more people try to get you to reconfigure, or potentially break your environment, is post the actual [tag:python] code/scripts you are using, and the [tag:cmd] command(s) you are using too. In order for us to assist you with an issue, we need to be able to reproduce it, and cannot do that without you supplying all relevant information.